# How to add spring animation every time when reaches the top and end of the scrollview in expo react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

In this code, spring animation only works if i first reaches to bottom then to top and so on. it is not working if i scroll to top consecutively. Please help me achieving this.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { ScrollView, View, Animated, Text, Button } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const layoutHeight = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
    const contentHeight = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;

    if (offsetY == 0 || offsetY + layoutHeight >= contentHeight) {
      // Reached top or bottom of ScrollView
      Animated.spring(scrollY, {
        toValue: offsetY > 0 ? 50 : 0,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        overScrollMode="never"
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <Animated.View style={{ paddingVertical: 50, transform: [{ translateY: scrollY }] }}>
          {emptyArray.map((value, index) => (
            <Text key={index} style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>
              My Name {index}
            </Text>
          ))}
        </Animated.View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const emptyArray = Array(20).fill(0);
```